# Showing ads on certain scenes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, admob

I wanted show my admob ads, only on certain scenes though. How would I go about doing this? Could I saw, if certain scene is going then show ad? Because the ads have to be in the viewcontroller file right? If im correct, how would I make an if statement, trying to say, if scene is showing?

Comment: This is essentially a "how to communicate between scene and view controller" question of which there are plenty on this site. PS: I removed the questions regarding the app review process, as this is offtopic (not a programming question) but yes, if you resubmit, the app will start over in approval process.

Comment: Please leave an extract of code for us to help!